# iOS Swift Firebase Login/SignUp view popup

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storyboard, firebase-authentication

I'm new to iOS development and struggling with the Views-flow.

I now have the following sotryboard setup:
[image]

In the "Tab bar VC" I'm checking the auth status with Firebase. So if the user is logged out or the user logs out, I want to show the "AuthVC". Otherwise show me the "TabBarVC".

I have little experience with iOS sotryboards (just a few single view applications), so this is a little hard to get started with.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance,

Theo.

Answer (score 1):

Just check wether you have a currentUser in **`FIRAuth`** or not in `viewWillAppear:`:-

```
 if FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser() == nil{

    //Stay at tabBarVC
       }else{

        //Navigate to AuthVC

        }
```

Comment: I knwo that I have to use this code block. But where in my App do I need to run this, and how to toggle between the "Tabbar VC" and "AuthVC" thanks.